# Passing data into my view from my controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, variables

I have built a layout template for my project (**see layout function**). The template system adds the header, footer and left to the page, also renders the current view as `"middle"`.

Problem is I cant include the `$data` variable correctly. This is to get my data to print out, I need to Include it like in Option 1 bellow.

**Option 1**

```
  $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
```

**layout function**

```
                public function layout () {
                $this->template['header'] = $this->load->view('layout/header', $this->Front_End_data, true);
                $this->template['left'] = $this->load->view('layout/left', $this->Front_End_data, true);
                $this->template['middle'] = $this->load->view($this->middle, $this->Front_End_data, true);
                $this->template['footer'] = $this->load->view('layout/footer', $this->Front_End_data, true);
                $this->load->view('layout/index', $this->template);
```

**This works renders the template, but I need `$data` to be included**

```
function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('user_profile/profiles_model');
    $query = $this->profiles_model->get_bank();

    if (!empty($query)) {
        $data['records'] = $query;
    }

    $this->middle = 'profile_view';
    $this->layout();
}
```

What would be the best solution for this?

**UPDATE**

I have tried something seems to partially work but replicates the view twice, one in the right place one wrong, any idea?

```
function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->model('user_profile/profiles_model');
        $query = $this->profiles_model->get_bank();

        if (!empty($query)) {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }
//        $this->middle = 'profile_view';
        $this->load->view($this->middle = 'profile_view',$data);
        $this->layout();
//        $this->layout($data);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This also works, but is not the nicest way of doing it

```
function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->model('user_profile/profiles_model');
        $query = $this->profiles_model->get_bank();

        if (!empty($query)) {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

//        $this->load->view($this->middle = 'profile_view',$data);
        $this->template['middle'] = $this->load->view ($this->middle = 'profile_view',$data, true);
        $this->layout();

//        $this->middle = 'profile_view';
//        $this->layout($data);
    }
```

Comment: What's the template?  A view? A library? Your question isn't descriptive.

Comment: @Kisaragi Ok thanks, Il fix up my question

Comment: here is another approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909964/best-way-to-implement-dynamic-menus-headers-footer-using-codeignitor/34911214#34911214

Comment: @cartalot thanks il have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not elegant, but here is how I fixed it

```
$this->template['middle'] = $this->load->view ($this->middle = 'pages/update_view',$data, true);
        $this->layout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template) created by Phil Sturgeon. It is awesome and extremely easy to setup and use. Any projects I build with codeigniter this is the first thing I add. Why recreate the wheel when there's already a plane available?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply pass `$data` to the layout method?

```
    $this->layout($data);
```

Comment: Hmm I thought about this, but the data dose not render