# How to simplify redundant calling of views in CI

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

On my application, the header and footer section is almost always static. The middle section contains the dynamic data which I load to a view and then append it to the header and footer view.

Example :

view/header:

```
<html>
<head><titile>My App</title></head>
<body>
```

view/footer

```
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
public function page1($contents){

$page  = $this->load->view('header',null,true);
$page .= '<div>' . $contents . '</div>';
$page .= $this->load->view('footer', null, true);

echo $page;
}
```

The above example may look too simplistic, but in cases when my static views become more than just the header and the footer, the code becomes very redundant whenever I need to build my view. Is there any way to simplify this in a function? (preferably create a class in the  library)

Comment: fyi if in the future you need more complicated templates this is a different approach but works well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909964/best-way-to-implement-dynamic-menus-headers-footer-using-codeignitor/34911214#34911214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the CORE by creating a MY_controller extension and defining a function there, but if you prefer it in the LIBRARY then create a class like this:

```
Class Viewer(){

     public function __construct(){
          // CREATE AN INSTANCE OF THE CONTROLLER CLASS LIBRARY
          $this->CI =& get_instance(); 
    }


     // Where $content is your dynamic content from another view; 
     public function final_view($content){
        $final_view  =  $this->CI->load->view('header',null,true);
        $final_view .=  $content;
        $final_view .=  $this->CI->load->view('footer',null,true);

        return $final_view;
       }
}
```

On your controller, re-using your code above: (Assuming that you have auto-loaded the library Viewer [auto-loading in CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html));

```
public function page1($contents){

     $dynamic_content = '<div>' . $contents . '</div>';
     echo $this->viewer->final_view($dynamic_content);
}
```

On different functions, you can just do the same

```
public function page2($more_contents){

     $dynamic_content = '<h1>' . $more_contents . '</h1>';
     echo $this->viewer->final_view($dynamic_content);
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That is the old user guide link ellislab does not deal with codeigniter any more try and use http://www.codeigniter.com/docs links